# why $\mathbb{Z}_8$, $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ are not isomorphic groups.

Tags: group-theory

And find an example of a group of order 8 that is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8$ or $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Thank you.

Comment: Quaternion is one example. And $\mathbb{Z}_{8}$ have element order $8$ but the other 2 don't have. See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ has an element of order 8, but the other two do not. $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$x$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ has an element of order 4 but $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$x$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$x$\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ does not. Thus none of the groups are isomorphic to one another.

Dihedral group of order 8 is not abelian and hence is not isomorphic to any of the abelian groups you have mentioned.